# I want to get a price if i search a book name in a text file using a Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to get the price from a text file by only using the book name. When I search for a book name it should give me the price of that book from a text file `(book_name | author_name | price )`. So that I can calculate the total price.

My option code if i press `1` it will take me to `Buy_book()` function:

```
while $1
do
    Options

    echo "Choose your option :"
    read input
    case $input in
        1) Add_book;;
        2) Search_data ;;
        3) Show_book;;
        4) Buy_book;;
        5) clear ;;
        6) break;;
        *) echo " !!! YOU ENTER WRONG INPUT !!!";;
    esac
done
```

My `Buy_book()` function:

```
Buy_book()
{
    while $1
    do 
        Show_year
        read Book_buy
        case $Book_buy in 
        1)
        2)
        3)
        4) clear;;
        5) break;;
        esac
    done
}
```

My `Add_book()` function:

```
Add_book()
{
    echo "------------------------Harinder book shop------------------------\n\n"
    Show_year #function show_year

    read input

    echo "Enter book name:"
    read Book_name
    echo "Enter author name: "
    read Author_name
    echo "Enter price:"
    read Book_price

    case $input in
         1) echo "\t$Book_name\t\t | \t$Author_name\t\t | \t$Book_price " >> ~/Desktop/Harinder/"B.A 1"/list1;;
         2) echo "\t$Book_name\t\t | \t$Author_name\t\t | \t$Book_price " >> ~/Desktop/Harinder/"B.A 2"/list2;;
         3) echo "\t$Book_name\t\t | \t$Author_name\t\t | \t$Book_price " >> ~/Desktop/Harinder/"B.A 3"/list3;;
         4) echo "!!!  You Enter wrong input  !!!";;
    esac
}
```

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What's your question?